# Select query and unknow predicate value

Tags: sql

I have this table with this columns: Key,Type,Culture.

Key and Culture are PK.

I know the Key and Culture values before query execution.

```
select * from resources r where r.CULTURE = 'sk' and r.KEY = 'test';
```

But I'd like to perform a select which would select also all other records with the same Type as the record with Culture = 'sk' and Key = 'test'

Comment: It's not good to have `KEY` as a field name. It's a reserved word in most RDBMSs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM resources AS r WHERE r.type =
(SELECT type FROM resources s  where s.culture= 'sk' and s.key= 'test')
```

`culture` and `key` are PK, so you only get one value back for type for your subquery. That result is used to get all rows with that type. If the subquery would return multiple values, you can use `IN` instead of `=`.

Comment: I guess a join would perform worse ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a join, it could resolves performance issue.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM resources r
    INNER JOIN resources r2
        ON r.type = r2.type
WHERE r2.CULTURE = 'sk' 
AND r2.KEY = 'test'
```

Comment: Will the perform better then this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676783/select-query-and-unknow-predicate-value/6676822#6676822 ?